# Moving a Resque job between queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

Is there anyway to move a resque job between two different queues?

We sometimes get in the situation that we have a big queue and a job that is near the end we find a need to "bump up its priority."  We thought it might be an easy way to simply move it to another queue that had a worker waiting for any high priority jobs.

This happens rarely and is usually a case where we get a special call from a customer, so scaling, re-engineering don't seem totally necessary.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing built-in in Resque. You can use [`rpoplpush`](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) like:

```
module Resque
  def self.move_queue(source, destination)
    r = Resque.redis
    r.llen("queue:#{source}").times do
      r.rpoplpush("queue:#{source}", "queue:#{destination}")
    end
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/rafaelbandeira3/7088498

Answer (score 0):

If it's a rare occurrence you're probably better off just manually pushing a new job into a shorter queue.  You'll want to make sure that your system has a way to identify that the job has already run and to bail out so that when the job in the long queue is finally reached it is not processed again (if double processing is a problem for you).